# vscode pylint extension -rcfile arg must be set to an absolute path?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint

I've been trying to set a different .pylintrc file per project, as I work with 10s of repositories, each might have different settings.
Since pylint is not an extension, this seems impossible.

When I'm setting the following args in my user's settings.json, the pylint file is not being found by pylint:
either a relative path

```
"pylint.args": [ "--rcfile=.pylintrc" ]
```

or using ${workspaceFolder} var:

```
"pylint.args": [ "--rcfile=${workspaceFolder}.pylintrc" ]
```

Both generates:

> [info] The config file ${workspaceFolder}.pylintrc doesn't exist!

The only option that works for me is specifying the absolute path of the rcfile, but as I mentioned, each repository has it's own file.
This works:

```
"pylint.args": [ "--rcfile=/home/actual/path/to/the/file/.pylintrc" ],
```

Am I missing something? Or is the extension does not support relative paths for args?